# ¿Cómo puede hacer para que me muestre un mensaje de confirmación al pulsar JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION en mi JFrame en JAVA?

Tags: java, poo, java-swing, eclipse, java-8

Lo que quiero hacer es que se muestre un mensaje al momento de querer cerrar la ventana completa y no se quite por defecto.

Este método muestra el mensaje de confirmación:

```
private void salir() {
    if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "¿Está seguro que desea salir?", "Salir", 
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

El siguiente método es de WindowListener, y manda a llamar al método salir:

```
@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    salir();
}
```

Yo lo mando a llamar dentro de mi constructor de la siguiente manera:

```
this.addWindowListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer se soluciona indicando que la operación por defecto que se ejecutará al intentar cerrar una ventana sea: *NADA* (`DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`). El comportamiento por defecto para los `JFrame`s es que se esconda la ventana (`HIDE_ON_CLOSE`), lo mismo que si hicieras esto: `jframe.setVisible(false)`.

Esto se hace a través del método [`JFrame#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)) (este método está disponible en todas las clases que representan algún tipo de ventana: `JDialog`, `JInternalFrame`, etc.).

```
// En el contructor de la clase que hereda de `JFrame`
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

Ahora la aplicación solo se cerrará cuando el usuario así lo indique pulzando el botón ***Yes*** de diálogo.